# Isekai manga where the main character dies and gets to see his own funeral as a ghost, and is then reincarnated by gods into another world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I suddenly remembered this manga in the shower but can't remember its name. I may be misremembering some part of this intro as it has been a while since I read this.

It starts when the main character (MC) dies and gets to see his own funeral as a ghost. Then gods show up and tell him that he can wish for anything, so the MC asks if they can make it so the people at his funeral forget about him. The gods come to like him because of his selflessness, so they reincarnate him into another world with his memories, as per his request in the answer he gave, where only he remembers them, so it makes the pain of his death only go to him.

Comment: Was this manga mostly in black & white or in full colour?

Comment: It was black and white

Comment: Do you know about when you would have read this? You say it's been a while, would that be a year? 3 years? 10?

Comment: About a year or two ago

Comment: Do you remember anything about how he died, or how old he was when he died? Did he reincarnate as a child with another family, or was he sent over in his original body? Do you remember anything about what happens after the reincarnation? This is likely the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261186 , which mentions a sister. Does this remind you of anything from the story?

Comment: Yep it's the same manga

Comment: no its not its entirely different it has the same begining but in a different way, as soon as he dies he tells the god/goddesse to reincarnate him but his sister also gets summoned.

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Isekai Tensei no Boukensha](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/isekai-tensei-no-boukensha)*

> Ootori Tenma, who lost his parents and was raised by his grandfather’s and grandmother’s friends who are living in the countryside, loses his life at the age of 25. A god of a different world called out to the ghost Tenma. This is a story about Tenma who, is liked by multiple Gods of reincarnation, receives multiple cheats and lives a second life in another world.

He dies and sees his own funeral...

[image: Funeral]

A god shows up and invites him to another world, and offers him a single wish...

[image: Forget about it]

Specifically, that everyone else will forget about him, so that no one will be mourn his death.

Comment: No mention of a sister that I see, so the other question about erasing everyone's memory is indeed a different series.