# Isekai manga where main characters dies and asks a God/Goddess to erase everyone's memory of him, so they won't feel sad

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I remember a manga where the main character dies, so the God/Goddess asks him for anything. He wishes that every one would forget about him and for the God/Goddess to erase everyone's memory of him, so they won't feel sad, and for the God/Goddess to watch over his sister. There is no record of his sister existing, but she is alive. She is the only one who remembers him, so God/Goddess summons her to where her brother is.

If anyone knows this manga please tell me.

Comment: Possibly asking about the same manga as the one in this unanswered question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260940/isekai-manga-where-the-main-character-dies-and-gets-to-see-his-own-funeral-as-a

Comment: About when did you read this? Do you remember anything about how he died, or how old he was when he died? Did the god/goddess summon her sister immediately after he reincarnated, or did it take a few chapters? When they reincarnated, were they in their original bodies or did they get reborn as different people?

Comment: it was a year ago all i know is that he riencarnated to another world with a sister who never forgot about him because her existing was not supposed to happen.

Comment: Do oyu have an idea about which setting they landed in after being reincarned? e.g. midieval village, in a huge quite advanced socienty full of political shenanigans etc.?

Comment: well it was widieval years but he reincarnated in a forest and later on ih his sister was too the reason why she was summoned was because she was never supposed exist on earth there was no record of her but she was alive.

Comment: Do you remember if this was mostly black&white or if it was in full color?

Comment: it was black and white

Comment: Hey in the manga in question does he take the book of death the goddess has and is then punished by the goddess?       Well it doesn't have to be a book of death but just a book in general where it shows the status of every living being

Comment: Alright I have it saved on one of the many sites I use I will try to find it

Comment: @I'dliketoBeimmortal Possibly isekai Munchkin. That has a book held by a goddess that includes information on everyone in her world, including the MC's sister. Which he steals and goes to look for his sister. But there's no funeral scene - the MC doesn't die at all, nor is he selfless.

Comment: thats not it it seems sorry i didn't answer earlier but it's not that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if you are mixing up multiple stories here.  I remember vaguely a couple where the main character asks to be forgotten, so no-one will mourn him.

But the second part sound very much like "*Seichou Cheat de Nandemo Dekiru you ni Natta ga, Mushoku dake wa Yamerarenai you desu*" a.ka. Growth Cheat.  The main character gets accidentally blessed by two goddesses, giving him 400x XP growth.  And he learns he can meet the goddesses again by clearing dungeons.  When he does, he asks the first goddess if he sister is okay.  The goddess promises to check, but as soon as the MC is gone, she notes that he isn't supposed to have a sister, and starts to investigate.

> It turns out his sister is the reincarnation of the demon lord from the isekai world, and she later arranges to get returned to that world.  But she does so on her own, not with help from the goddesses.

Also, while the MC of Growth Cheat does not request to be erased, we do find out that he has disappeared from photographs and his sister is the only one who remembers him, for the reason spoiled above.

Comment: @BLACKVEHETA Is it possible you're combining details from this and "Isekai Tensei no Boukensha", the answer I proposed to the other similar question? That includes the funeral and "everyone should forget about me", but no sister that I saw, while this has the disappearing sister.

Comment: sorry bro turns out it was this one 

Comment: @BLACKVEHETA Could you accept this answer so it will show as the correct story?